# Magento: Different sizes and colors under one simple product?

Tags: magento

I’m setting up an online clothing store and have come across a huge problem:

When I make at product (a t-shirt for example), I want to be able to add the available sizes and colors, without having to create a product for every single option.

When I add a color or size, I need to be able to enter a SKU for each product, so I can tell which option the customer chose in the store. First I tried making 2 sets of attributes: “Color” and “Size”, so I could multi-select when adding a product. But the attributes didn’t show up as options in the store, as I had hoped.

I did a lot of searching, and found that some people used the “Costom Option” tab, to make fields for the available sizes, colors etc. - but I don’t want add those options every time I add a product. The multi-select feature I accomplished with the attributes, would have been perfect.

Also I found that someone was forced to pay for an extension to accomplish this - but as I am running on a very tight budget, so I really don’t want to pay anything to achieve this.

Comment: Do you mean that you do not wish to use a Configurable product?  In my understanding, that is the only way to get attributes to appear as selectable options on the product page.  (if you do go that route, the attributes need to be Global, Dropdown, and Used in Configurable Product (when you create the attributes).  Of course you will have to create each individual simple product using a base configurable product's Associated Products tab (the Super Products Attribute Configuration -- unfortunately this thing doesn't let the images, categories, etc carry over into each simple product)

Comment: ^^^ meaning that you'll have to readd images for every single simple product -- at least that's my experience.  Therefore it makes sense if you want to avoid making all of those simple products for each color/size, but then if you just use product options, is it not true that you won't be able to have inventory/stock tracking?  Sorry I am not familiar with using options yet, but wanted to make sure you understood about the configurable product type.  It is still a lot of tedious work using configurable products..

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this programmatically, observing the product save and generate all simple products of a configurable product. Unfortunately, you will have to manage stock for those items separately.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating a configurable products. For more information on how to create configurable products please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-configurable-product. You can refer to http://www.srota.co for an example.